# Is there a way to add Query string in URL after webform submission and remove the ?token from confirmation page

Tags: webforms

Actually, I would like to add `?sid=submission_id` in the url except `?token=random_token_value` after webform submission. Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write a custom WebformHandler.

BTW, the sid is not being passed to the confirmation page for security reasons because malicious users would be able to guess a submission's sid and then see a submission's confirmation page.